# How to create a new ODBC connection to one remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, odbc, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run an application that I've developped recently. This one uses an ODBC connection to browse a defined database.

I'm trying to execute this app from a remote computer. Using VMWare, I've created a new Windows 7 environment and connected on. After that I've tried to create a new `System DSN`, but, when I set the logins that I'm using to connect on my local SQL Server 2008 I get

> Connection failed: SQLState: '28000' SQL Server Error: 18452
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed. The login
>   is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows
>   authentication.

How may I to deal with this, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use SQL Server authentication to connect or add the local machine to the same domain where the server is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

Comment: I've created a new Login which uses SQL Server authentication, and when I try to connect using these logins I get `Login failed for user 'Username'`.

Comment: It's either a wrong password or login name, pls recheck. Also, once you create a login, give it access to the database (from "user mapping" page of login properties dialog in SSMS).