# Connecting R to an MS SQL database on a Mac using RODBC

Tags: sql-server, r, macos, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to an MS SQL database from R (on a Mac) - after fiddling a lot with odbc.ini, odbcinst.ini, and installing freeTDS as described:

```
sudo port install freetds +mssql +odbc +universal
```

it now works on the Mac's command line level, but when trying to access it from R using the command:

```
con <- odbcConnect("myDSN", uid = "myID", pwd = "myPWD")
```

it just hangs and when forced to stop executing, I get 50+ of the following warnings:

```
In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=myDSN;UID=myID;PWD=myPWD") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 1421220112, message [iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source 
name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded
```

After having tried to make it work for about two days, I'm running out of suggestions. Can anybody help point me to what I am missing?

EDIT: It also works when running R on the virtual Windows machine. How do I get it to work on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Did you first configure your MS SQL driver connection?  If you have, then you should have a data source called "myDSN" in the OCBC Data Source dialog box.

Here is a [great blog](http://brazenly.blogspot.sg/2014/05/r-how-to-connect-r-to-database-sql.html) which gives step-by-step instructions and screen captures for what you need to do.

When you issue queries in R, R will try to talk to the ODBC data source called "myDSN".  That data source knows what database you want (MS SQL) and also what the credentials (username/password) are needed to get access.  This is the reason why you must configure the data source.

Comment: I'm not using Windows and so have no control panel... I have a virtual windows machine, and yes, I did the DSN set-up on that, but still no go. I now consider running R on the virtual machine instead, maybe that'll work... The suggestions in the blog you linked to made no difference either, except trying to use `odbcDriverConnect` resulted in a different error message (specified driver could not be loaded...)

Comment: It would be good to try running `R` on the virtual machine.  Let us know whether that works.

Comment: It works from R on the virtual machine. But how do I get it to work on the Mac?

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934535/how-to-create-a-new-odbc-connection-to-one-remote-sql-server).